# Error when trying to connect to hub with SignalR in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, signalr

We are attempting to make a chat style app as a Chrome extension using SignalR. We have attempted to update the SignalR we were using from 1.1.3 to 2.0.0.

We are receiving this error when we load up the extension:

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
```

When we have the script in our HTML, then we still receive the error along with a GET error.

We also tried:

```
 <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

This is our connection setup:

```
connection = $.hubConnection('http://ourUrl');
```

Prior to that we used this to set up our chat:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
```

This is our chatProxy setup now:

```
chatProxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
```

We were not using a chat proxy in our initial setup.

They are followed by our hub.start:

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
```

We are calling the hub using:

```
chatProxy.invoke('methodName',
```

We were calling the hub using:

```
chat.server.methodName()
```

We were setting up our functions for the hub to call using:

```
chat.client.functionName = function (token) {
```

We are currently using this system to set up our functions for the hub to call:

```
chatProxy.on('loginSuccess', function (token) {
```

We are not sure why we are getting the errors and not sure how to fix the code due to the fact that we have basically followed the signalR 2.0.0 tutorial completely. It seems to function differently in a Chrome extension than it does in a Web app. Any ideas or input would be helpful, thank you.

Edit:
Our manifest looks like this:

```
{
"name": "String",
"description": "String",
"version": "1.2",
"app": {
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["/js/background.js", "/js/jquery-2.0.3.js", "/js/window.js", "/js/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js"]
  }
},
"icons": { "16": "/images/icon16.png", "128": "/images/icon128.png" },
"permissions": [ "http://ourUrl/" ]
}
```

All the javascript code is at the top of document.ready(). Within window.js.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "load up the extension" ? Also, please, give more info about your extension's structure (e.g. what does the manifest look like, where is the above code run from, what's in the background page/content scripts/popup etc).

Comment: When the extension is launched, the errors show in the console.

Comment: I am sure it doesn't, but that is not I asked for (read my comment above) :)

Comment: I edited the question instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: According to the tutorial, there should be a `/signalr/hubs` script in your webpage. I don't see any...

Comment: And what exactly is 'ourUrl' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should include a script to `http://yourDomain/signalr/hubs` in your page (in this case the extensions background page). But since your extension is on a different domain, you'll need to **[allow cross-domain requests](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain)**.

Comment: We added the script, but we seem to be missing something else as it is still not working correctly. We also are using "microsoft.owin.cors", and "microsoft.owin.hosting" to use "app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);", which was recommended by a co-worker to handle the cross-domain requests. It hasn't made a difference on that front. We are now getting both errors after we inserted appropriate script.

Comment: Hi @JonathanYoung, I don't expect you to remember after more than 2 years, but how did you got this fixed?